# What do the wire colors in the earphone jack mean?

Tags: wirebonding

What are the colors in the earphone jack? I've got four colors: bare copper, red,  green, and blue. It's a Samsung earphone.

Comment: Cable colours don't usually imply anything much generally. https://thewiredshopper.com/headphone-wire-color-code/

Comment: How can I identify.?

Comment: Whatever the designer chose them to be. If you are making volume production, you can order your custom cable to have any colors you want. Bare copper I would assume is ground.

Comment: I don't think these have standard colours. However, you can use your multimeter's beep mode to identify them easily enough. Touch one probe to each section of the plug, and the other one to each wire (e.g. you might need to strip the ends, or touch where they are soldered to if they are still soldered)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a color code standard for headsets or earphones.  Each manufacturer seems to make up their own.

If you need to figure out what each wire in your headset does, then you will have to measure them with an ohmmeter to find out.

Start with the plug.  [The plug connections for smart phones are standardized:](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec)

[image]

The colored segments of the plug in the upper left corner represent the segments of a four pole headset plug.

- L (blue) = left earphone
- R (orange) = right earphone
- GND (green) = common for all earphones and the microphone
- MIC (purple) = microphone

Use a multimeter in "Ohms" mode to measure between the segments and the end of each of the colored wires in the headset.

I did this [a year ago for a headset of my own.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/howtosolder-17-headset) and came up with this color map:

[image]

That is almost certainly not the same as yours.

Note that the wires are insulated, even the one that looks like bare copper.  In modern headsets, the wires are made of fine strands of copper that are then coated in a colored paint.  The one that looks like bare copper is covered in transparent paint.

You can't measure resistance to the wire itself.  You will have to measure between the pin on the plug and the end of the wire where it is soldered to the earphone or microphone.

Comment: My set have Red/Gold for speaker/gnd to one ear, and green/gold speaker/gnd + blue/red mic/gnd to the other ear. My previous set of the exact same product from the same manufacturer had a different colour set. As you say, the colours are anyones guess, and even vary within the same product over time.